# How do I add a fadeIn effect in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I got the following javascript code:

```
function myProfileIn() {
    var showme = document.getElementById("myProfileTop").fadeIn(2000);
    showme.style.display = "inline";
    var showme = document.getElementById("myProfileMain").fadeIn(2000);
    showme.style.display = "inline";
}
```

This code works on my buttons as `"onclick="myProfileIn();"` so they get to be visible but i also want to include a fadein effect when the button is clicked.
That is why i included `".fadeIn(1000)"` but this is not working.

Here is the button which activates the function:

```
<div id="profileButtonArea"><div id="profileButtonBox"><img onclick="myProfileIn();" id="profileButtonImg" src="<?php echo $userPath; ?>" /></div></div>
```

And here are the two elements(divs) which are blended in:

```
<div id="myProfileTop" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="myProfileMain" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that `fadeIn()` is a jQuery method. It's not available on a standard HTMLElement object. Also note that if you want to toggle the element's visibility on successive clicks use `fadeToggle()`.

You should also use unobtrusive Javascript to attach your event handlers as `on*` event attributes are now considered outdated. As you've tagged the question with jQuery. Here's a working example for all of the above:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#profileButtonBox img').click(function() {
    $("#myProfileTop, #myProfileMain").stop(true).fadeToggle(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#myProfileTop,
#myProfileMain {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profileButtonArea">
  <div id="profileButtonBox">
    <img id="profileButtonImg" src="yourimage.jpg" title="click me" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myProfileTop">myProfileTop</div>
<div id="myProfileMain">myPropfileMain</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this code now and this works but does ".fadeIn()" automaticly overwrite the "display:none" attribute or what is happening there? How come that it changes without me telling the css style to change @Rory McCrossan

Comment: I want the div to fadeout again too when clicken the same button so i think this has to be done with onclick afterall :/ @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Yes, `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` automatically set the `display` property for you. In your case of toggling use `fadeToggle()`. I've updated my example for you

Comment: Also note the use of `stop()` which clears the current animation in progress and immediately starts the next. If you're not familiar with jQuery I'd suggest you have a quick read of http://api.jquery.com

Comment: ok perfect, so when this .stop() is with in the variable it starts the animation of both id's at the same time? Did I understand that right in the api? By the way, I got two of those functions and when one is activated and I click on a other button to activate that function, how do I deactivate the previous one? :) @Rory McCrossan

Comment: I'd start a new question for that one